# Python/regex: Change 4th Octet of all IP addresses in a file to .0

Tags: python, regex

I have been battling with this for over a day now; haven't done Python for 3 years now and its showing!
I want the code to work through the file and using substitute I want to change the last octet of each IP address to 0.  The re sub line just isn't working and instead of the IP address I get the following in the output file:

<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x000000000342D718>0

Which is the regex match object plus the 0 that I want as the last octet.

## And the code....

```
import fileinput
import re, sys, os

file1 = 'output.txt'

ipv4Regex = re.compile(r'[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}')


def Octet_4_0():
    for line in fileinput.input():
        line = ipv4Regex.sub(str(re.search(ipv4Regex,line))+'.'.join(ipv4Regex.split('.')[:-1]+["0"]), line.strip())
        #print(line)
        with open(file1, 'a') as f:
            f.write(line+'\n')
    fileinput.close()

print "Current working dir : %s" % os.getcwd() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Delete the previous file
    try:
        os.remove(file1)
    except OSError:
        pass
    # Run the  function
    Octet_4_0()
```

Comment: `ipv4Regex` is a compiled regex. What do you expect `ipv4Regex.split('.')` to return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest keeping it simple and just match all IP addresses with the help of a capture group:

```py
ip = 'some text here 127.123.456.789 blah blah'
ip_out = re.sub(r'\b(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\.\d+\b', r'\1.0', ip)
print(ip_out)  # some text here 127.123.456.0 blah blah
```

Comment: The regex could be tightened up if you have other patterns with digits and dots in them. There are many examples of such regexes so I won't attempt to ad-lib one here. Maybe check that each octet is in the range 0-255 and maybe check that the boundaries are actually whitespace and not e.g. dots.

Comment: @tripleee OK...but who says there couldn't be an English sentence which happens to end in `1.2.3.4.`, where the final dot is a stop?  You're right about the IP regex, I could have made that tighter.  It isn't clear that the OP would be expecting anything else which would match the above regex _other_ than an IP address.

Comment: It's working an absolute treat Tim, thanks a million mate.  I'm trying to make firewall rules out a weeks worth of Checkpoint logs. The regex you suggested doesn't conflict with any of the other data. Thanks again !!

Comment: I was going to say i'd shout you a beer if I could, but I just saw the buy me a coffee link on your page. So tomorrows coffee is on me mate.

Comment: @woodze You rock brother! `:-)`